# expectJ - Reading InputStream from spawn.send()

Tags: java, inputstream, expectj

With the following code I'd like to read the InputStream from `spawn.send("ls | grep *.dat\n");`. My calss implements `Spawnable` and it's method `getStdout()`, but have no clue how to use it.
ExpectJ docs says: `getStdout()` - Get a stream from which the Spawn's stdout can be read. But this doesn't get me any futher.

```
    private void expectC() throws IOException, TimeoutException, ExpectJException, InterruptedException {   
        ExpectJ expectJ = new ExpectJ();
        Spawn spawn = expectJ.spawn("192.168.1.60", 22, "login", "pass");
        spawn.send("ls | grep *.dat\n");
        spawn.expectClose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ExpectJ ex = new ExpectJ(5);
    Spawn spawn = ex.spawn(new SshSpawn("192.168.56.101", 22, "alice", "password"));
    String command = "ls | grep dat \n";
    spawn.send(command);
    try{
        spawn.expectClose();
    }catch(Exception e){}
    String lsResults = spawn.getCurrentStandardOutContents().split("grep dat")[2];
    String[] lsRows = lsResults.split("\r\n"); //remove the 1st and the last
```